# Unexplainable change of line spacing

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I am currently writing my bachelor's thesis and have encountered some very peculiar behavior in LaTeX which I frankly cannot explain.

I am using the `setspace` package and have `\onehalfspacing` set at the beginning of my document and do not change it until a table at the end of the document. However, for some reason and without any action of my own, at a seemingly random spot, the spacing of my document automatically changes from `onehalfspacing` to `singlespacing`.

I'd appreciate any ideas on what the reason could be.
I have attached an image of the generated PDF in which the spacing change is clearly visible (pretty much at the end of the page, it goes on after that for the whole document) and of my code at the same location.
Note: The `\setmeter` function is a custom function which is also used several times beforehand, thus probably not being the cause.
I have also tried manually setting to `\onehalfspacing` and `\setstretch{1.5}` at the place where it changes, which does not seem to help.

[image: The generated PDF]
[image: The code]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do not post code as images, but rather paste a text snippet into the post (you can format it with the `{}` buttons).

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: \singlespacing can affect text *before* the command if you don't have a paragraph break before.

Comment: I second TeXnician's request: In particular it would be great if you could reproduce the problem in a short, but complete example document, an MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. The ```\\``` is definitely suspicious. You should also not have to write `\textbf{...}` to get a heading-like title. Note that some people (for example me) would say that the `\textit{standard \textbf{rock} beat} von \textsc{Moore}` contains quite a lot of font changes in a small portion of text, that might look a bit restless...

Comment: You may also want to write `--` instead of `-` for *Gedankenstriche*. The single `-` is usually a hyphen (*Bindstrich*)

Comment: Maybe try `\paragraph{Der standard rock beat -- Mythos oder Realit\"at?}` instead of your manual formatting

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischers comment, I figured it out. I had a longtabu in the same section after the text that had singlespacing activated.
After changing the code, the spacing was fine again. Here is the longtabu code that caused the issue:

```
\tabulinesep=0.8mm
\singlespacing
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {
    X[3,c]
    X[3,c]
    X[4,c]}
    \hline
    \textbf{Interpret} & 
    \textbf{Anzahl Stücke} & 
    \textbf{Genre-Zuordnung}
    \\ \hline \hline
    Lionel Richie & 2 & Motown-Sound, Pop, Rhythm and Blues, Soft Soul\\ \hline
    Blondie & 1 & New Wave, Pop\\ \hline
    Diana Ross & 1 & Motown-Sound, Pop, Rhythm and Blues, Soul\\ \hline
    Kenny Rogers & 1 & Country, Pop\\ \hline
    Rick Springfield & 1 & AOR, Pop, Rock\\ \hline
    Joan Jett & 1 & Hard Rock, Pop\\ \hline
    Bonnie Tyler & 1 & Pop\\ \hline
    Phil Collins & 1 & AOR, Pop\\ \hline
    Tina Turner & 1 & Pop, Rhythm and Blues\\ \hline
    Kenny Loggins & 1 & AOR, Pop, West Coast\\ \hline
\end{longtabu}
```

The \singlespacing in the second line is what caused the unexpected behavior, since it was in the same paragraph.

Comment: Your write-up may create the impression that the switch in line spacing is related to the presence of a `longtabu` environment. That's not the case. Instead,it's related to the presence of the `\singlespacing` directive -- and the absence of any paragraph breaks.